# How to set shadowColor on ActionBarSherlock's title?

Tags: android, colors, shadow, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I know how to set shadowColor on other view, but on ActionBarSherlock's title, shadow isn't showing.

here my style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


  <resources>
<style name="Theme.SherlockClient" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
       <item name="abTitleTextStyle">@style/CustomTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Turquoise</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/Green</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">3</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to confirm have you defined you custom style `@style/Theme.SherlockClient` in application tag in manifest instead of `@style/Theme.Sherlock`

Comment: yes I did, I had the same problem with the menu text, and the problem disappeared by itself after several compilations without my coming to this part of the code. There are cache problems in eclipse?

Comment: surprised the problem fixed itself on its own. I cant get it to work without the fix described http://stackoverflow.com/a/9908958/236743